# Why is this an answer?

Tags: discussion, support

[Why is this considered an answer:](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28044/short-story-about-alien-military-telepathy/49588#49588)

1. It doesn't give a title or author.
2. It adds to the question, but in more of a comment sort of way.

So should this be a answer due to its size or a comment(when modified). Either way it adds to the question, but it just doesn't answer it; just adds description.

It's like a copy of the question, but in the answer spot. If this(my post) is a duplicate question or has a simple answer I will delete it(for quality control).

### Additional Question

- Would I flag this answer?

---

I flagged it with this reason:
***"This answer could probably be deleted and no one would miss it as the question was answered and the question has some description."***

And this is what happened when I did.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I'd dispute it if someone flagged it for removal. Although it doesn't answer the question directly (which would usually push it into the status of a comment), it does meet the requirements of a "*partial answer*", as described in the [FAQ](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

> **Have the same problem?**
>
> Still no answer to the question, and you have the same problem? Help
>   us find a solution by researching the problem, then **contribute the
>   results of your research and anything additional you’ve tried as a
>   partial answer.** That way, even if we can’t figure it out, the next
>   person has more to go on. You can also vote up the question or set a
>   bounty on it so the question gets more attention.

On top of that, the answer does contain some useful detail (e.g. mentioning the horn, mentioning that it dates to the 1960s) that wasn't in the original question. That extra info would be lost if you removed the answer.

Comment: It could be converted to a comment and the info would not be lost.

Comment: @phantom42 It excess the max comment length by ~200 chars. It would need some editing to become a comment, which I don’t think mods generally do for answer ~> comment conversions.

Comment: @phantom42 additionally comments are ephemeral. They may be deleted anytime and the info'd be lost yet again